# Magento 2 bind param to query in order by clause

Tags: magento2, database, collection, query, zend-framework

I'm trying to bind params to order by with expressions clause in Magento 2, my insecure code looks like:

```
$order = new \Zend_Db_Expr("POW((main_table.long - $this->_coordinates['lat']), 2) + POW((main_table.lat - {$this->_coordinates['lat']}), 2)");

                $stores->getSelect()->order(array(
                    $order,
                    'main_table.title ASC'
                ));
```

How could I bind both variables to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finnaly found the answer, I moved my filter codes to Collection class, when extending "Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection", you can use `$this->addBindParam($name, $value)`. Follow my final model code:

```
$this->addBindParam(':lat', $args['coordinates']['lat']);
        $this->addBindParam(':long', $args['coordinates']['long']);

        $order = new \Zend_Db_Expr("POW((main_table.long - :long), 2) + POW((main_table.lat - :lat), 2) ASC");

        $this->getSelect()->order(array(
            $order,
            'main_table.title ASC'
        ));
```